# can we use past simple with for the past two days

Tags: meaning

I  **heard**  some strange noises for the past two days after waking up and it **scared** me, I'm glad it did not happen today

if I consider that the strange noises are over and won't happen again

or

I **have been hearing** or **have heard**  some strange noises for the past two days after waking up and it **has scared** me, I'm glad it did not happen today

if I consider it may happen again

Am I right

Comment: I heard some strange noises for the past two days and it scared me ,I am glad it has not happened today is it ok because we can used past simple with a duration I played football for two hours

Comment: but I want to know why it is not possible to use past simple ,I have seen diuration with past simple why it is not possible in this case you did not explain why it was not possible and in my new question i changed the end , i used present perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, noises started at a certain point in the past and ended at a certain later point in the past, so in this case you can use the **past perfect continuous tense** ([Englishpage.com](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html)):

> I *had been hearing* some strange noises for the past two days after
>   waking up and it *had been scaring me,* so I'm glad it did not
>   happen today.

(*It did not happen today* is in the past tense, because it refers to a distinct time in the past.)

If the noises started 2 days ago and they still last, you say it in the **present perfect continuous tense** ([Englishpage.com](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html)):

> I *have been hearing*...

You can also use the **past simple tense** for something that started and ended in the past ([Englishpage.com](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html)):

> I *heard* some strange noises for two days.

In this case, the emphasis is on when you heard noises and not for how long they were lasting.

The **past continuous tense** is usually reserved for ongoing actions in the past that were *interrupted* by another (usually short) event in the past ([Englishpage.com](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html)), so it may not be best for your example.

So, you can write *all* parts of the sentence in the past tense:

> I heard some strange noises for the past two days after waking up and
>   it scared me a lot; I'm glad it *did not happen* today.

You have two sentences, so you need to separate them with a semicolon or just write it as two sentences.

Comment: Thanks for answering me all is clear for me now