# Past simple or past progressive for a duration

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-continuous

is it possible to write

I heard some strange noises for the past two days after waking up  and it scared me. I am glad I have not heard them today

I was hearing some strange noises for the past two days after waking up and it was scaring me. I am glad I have not heard them today

I want to express that the strange noises lasted only 2 days and today is  back to normality

Comment: I answered this here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/238896/can-we-use-past-simple-with-for-the-past-two-days

Comment: but I want to  know why it is not possible to use past simple ,I have seen diuration with past simple why it is not possible in this case you did not explain why it was not possible  and in my new question i changed the end , i used present perfect

Comment: I edited my previous answer: Yes, you can use past simple tense for the duration in the past, when you want to say _when_ it happened and  you don't need to _emphasize_ the duration.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two tenses I think. To me "for the past two days" means:  (today is Wednesday) from Monday until today. That requires present perfect.

If you want to express the noises stopped before today, so they occurred Monday and Tuesday, use past simple.

You are trying to combine the two and that is not possible.

"To hear" is a stative verb, it is normally not used in the continuous tense. The only time "to hear"is used in the continuous is in the sense of hearing voices in your head, which occurs with mental illness.